# How to create a linebreak after line continuation symbol (\)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to pass a multi line command into the command line, the problem is that that requires using \ in the command, which is also the line continuation character in python. This results in the line breaks in the string to simply be ignored.

```
A = """line 1 \
line 2 \
line 3"""

print(A)

Returns:
line 1 line 2 line 3

Wanted return:
line 1 \
line 2 \
line 3
```

Is there a way to do this still?

Comment: Escapte the slashes: `A = """line 1 \\...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding more slashes:

```
>>> A = """line 1 \\
line 2 \\
line 3"""
>>> print(A)
line 1 \
line 2 \
line 3
>>>
```

Or escape it with `r""`:

```
>>> A = r"""line 1 \
line 2 \
line 3"""
>>> print(A)
line 1 \
line 2 \
line 3
>>>
```

`r` means the string is a raw string. So the text in it will be escaped.

Comment: I actually can't believe I didn't try that.... It worked, thank you!

Comment: @NFTLevi Your welcome :) Please click the accept mark ✔️ if my answer helped, also please click the triangle pointing up ▲ for upvoting as well.

Comment: @NFTLevi Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)